# Usando MobileAds.initialize em onCreateView

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment, admob

Olá estou desenvolvendo um app e desejo botar propagandas nele, só que  estou com uma dúvida que esta começando a se tornar preocupação, Meu app tem uma barra de navegação e utilizo fragmentos invés de activitys e toda vez que crio um novo fragmento sempre coloco MobileAds.initialize no onCreateView e funciona normalmente, mas o meu medo é que caso um usuário clique várias vezes pra chamar um fragmento, o admob entenda que está tendo um tráfego irregular e bana a minha conta. Isso pode acontecer? se sim como posso resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Sobre banir ou não eu não sei lhe dizer, mas eu também estou usando uma barra de navegação (buttom_bar) com fragments porem uma única actvity para todos eles, eu uso MVVM para não precisar de muitas activity's, na minha MainActivity  esta minha bottom bar e os anuncios apenas, desta forma os anuncios são requisitados junto a barra de navegação.

Resumindo, fiz uma unica requestAd e os anuncios estão visiveis em todos fragments. Espero ter ajudado... :)